# Filter json records in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I created a DRF API endpoint in order to be able to grab some data to my database and show it on my Django page using Jquery.

My sample data looks like this:

```
{
    "item": "Someitem",
    "Price": 120,
    "Status": "Free"
},
{
    "item": "SecondItem",
    "Price": 90,
    "Status": "Taken"
},
```

So if I retrieve the endpoint from JQuery to this link: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/`, I'll get all the records and have all of them shown in my web page. But what if, for example, I only want to retrieve **only** the records whose `Status` field is set to `Taken`? Is there any way to edit the DRF request so that it points to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/Taken`? Or instead, if the user wants to retrieve all the others with the status set to `Free`, it will point to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/Free`? I know I could do it with jquery, but I would actually like to do it server-side.

I tried with this:

```
queryset = tst.objects.filter(Status="Taken")
```

But the problem here, is that it will always take **only** the `Taken` records from my DB. In my case, I want to find a way to retrieve `Taken` sometimes, and `Free` some other times from the template.

I'm fairly new to DRF, so my setup is pretty basic:

**views.py**

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer


class tstDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
```

**url.py**

```
path('tst/', views.tstList.as_view()),
path('tst/<int:pk>/', views.tstDetail.as_view()),
```

**models.py**

```
class tst(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField()
    Price = models.FloatField()
    Status = models.CharField()
   

    def save(self, *args, using=None, **kwargs):
        super(tst, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: your sample data... Are those data from models or you're sending them via frontend/jquery ?

Comment: They are from my model. stored in my db

Comment: What versions are you running? (`python --version`, `pip --version`, `pip show django`, `pip show django-filter`, `pip show djangorestframework`) Julien's answer works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.6.8, pip 19.2.3, django 2.2.6, django-filter 2.2.0, djangorestframework 3.10.3.

Comment: It's Python 3.6, Django 2.1.7, DRF 3.9.2, Django Filter 1.1.0

Comment: Ok. The problem was Django Filter. I had the 1.1 version, i needed the 2.0 version. Thanks a lot @krubo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on [DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters).
In your case, I'd suggest you install `django_filters`, then in your view:

```py
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ('Status',)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. Ok, i can put this in my view, but then how do i filter from here? I mean, how do i choose what 'Status' do i want? I mean 'Free' or 'Taken'

Comment: You can get examples from the browsable API, but adding ´?Status=Free´ at the end of your URL should work.

Comment: Tried it, i'm getting this error: cannot import name 'QUERY_TERMS' from 'django.db.models.sql.constants'

Comment: I think it should be a compatibility issue with Django 2.0

Comment: Which django version do you use ?

Comment: i'm usung Django 2.1.7

Comment: And django filters si 2.0?

Comment: No idea, but after searching for the error i got that it might be a compatibility issue

Comment: The problem was my Django Filter version. I needed the 2.0 version, not the 1.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

a few days ago i found and watched this video and i think it's useful for your question, (about model managers and querysets):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjUmA_pkGtw

Answer (score 1):

You can set the queryset by [django filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

```
queryset = tst.objects.filter(Status="Taken") # make sure the "Taken" is always Capitalized.
```

Comment: Yeah, that solution works. But this way, it waill always take the records set to 'Taken'. But what if, for example, i would like to call all the records with the Status set to free, from my template?

Comment: `tst.objects.filter(Status="Free")`

Comment: Do i need to add both the lines to my view? To which url should i connect, later?