# why does django-filter not work as expected

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have the below views.py file for my class based view.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .permissions import IsOwner, IsNotBlacklistedUser
from rest_framework import filters
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters_django

from core.models import Book
from .serializers import BookSerializer, AllBookSerializer


class BookApiView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsNotBlacklistedUser)
    filter_backends = (filters_django.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('title',)

    def get(self, request):
        books = Book.objects.filter(
            user=request.user.id, is_published=True).order_by('-title')
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(get, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = BookSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

I am unable to see any filter option when i load this view in the django rest framework UI . I am not sure how i should be doing this. Can someone point out what i might have to do extra to get this working . I have also added `'django_filters'` to my settings.py file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter json records in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531286/filter-json-records-in-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use ViewSets.

```
class BookApiViewSet(CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsNotBlacklistedUser)
    filter_backends = (filters_django.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('title',)
```

or generic APIViews

```
class BookListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )
     permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsNotBlacklistedUser)
     filter_backends = (filters_django.DjangoFilterBackend,)
     filter_fields = ('title',)
```

or you can extend GenericAPIView and write filters manually.

```
class BookApiView(GenericAPIView):
     authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )
     permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsNotBlacklistedUser)
     filter_backends = (filters_django.DjangoFilterBackend,)
     filter_fields = ('title',)
     queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
         if page is not None:
             serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

         serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
         return Response(serializer.data)
```

Note: I didn't test codes you may need to tweak little.